# logging session for facebook application

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to log session start and session end time for facebook applications?

Any inputs will be appreciated.

```
   $iframeSessionKeyName = $CONFIG['facebook']['apiKey'] . '_session_key';
   if (isset($_REQUEST[$iframeSessionKeyName])) {
    $_SESSION['fb_sig_session_key'] = $_REQUEST[$iframeSessionKeyName];
    }
    else if (isset($_REQUEST['fb_sig_session_key'])) {
    $_SESSION['fb_sig_session_key'] = $_REQUEST['fb_sig_session_key'];
       }
   if  (! empty($_SESSION['fb_sig_session_key']))     
   $this->facebook->api_client->session_key = $_SESSION['fb_sig_session_key'];

This is not working.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the information provided by the Facebook API?

Comment: @Tobbe: $iframeSessionKeyName = $CONFIG['facebook']['apiKey'] . '_session_key';
if (isset($_REQUEST[$iframeSessionKeyName])) {
    $_SESSION['fb_sig_session_key'] = $_REQUEST[$iframeSessionKeyName];
}
else if (isset($_REQUEST['fb_sig_session_key'])) {
    $_SESSION['fb_sig_session_key'] = $_REQUEST['fb_sig_session_key'];
}
if (! empty($_SESSION['fb_sig_session_key'])) $this->facebook->api_client->session_key = $_SESSION['fb_sig_session_key'];

Answer (score 0):

There is not much overview of your problem but still [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) is worth a read

Comment: :I should be able to log the session start and end time for my application.

Comment: **FB.getLoginStatus allows you to determine if a user is logged in and connected to your app.** So the answer to your question is NO

Comment: :How do i log session? Is it possible or not